# unzipping .fsd file

Tags: android

I am using the following code for unzipping a `.fsd` file, but it is showing the exception:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Central Directory Entry not found
```

My code is:

```
public void unzipFolder(String zipfile_name,String unzipfolder_name){
    System.out.println("zip file nme----"+zipfile_name);

    try {
        ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipfile_name);
        System.out.println("zip file size----"+zf.size());
        Enumeration< ? extends ZipEntry> zipEnum = zf.entries();
        String dir = unzipfolder_name;

        while( zipEnum.hasMoreElements() ) {
        ZipEntry item = (ZipEntry) zipEnum.nextElement();

        if (item.isDirectory()) {
        File newdir = new File(dir + File.separator + item.getName());
        newdir.mkdir();
        } else {
        String newfilePath = dir + File.separator + item.getName();
        File newFile = new File(newfilePath);
        if (!newFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        copyInputStream(zf.getInputStream(item),
                   new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newfilePath)));

        }
        }
        zf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


public static final void copyInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Zip -> copyInputStream : "+e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Here `zipfile_name=/mnt/sdcard/forside_bookshelf_download/P160225200007046510000718MASenC.fsd`, and `unzipfolder_name=/mnt/sdcard/`.

I got the above exception in the following line:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipfile_name);
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue once with zip4j.
It was solved when i added a main folder inside the zipfile, and put all the other content in there.

Comment: Thanks jelle for your reply,can you please clarify clearly how you unzip it.

Comment: The structure in the zipfile is like this: file.zip / data / filetoUnzip.png
`final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path);
final FileHeader fileHeader = zipFile.getFileHeader("data/fileToUnzip.png");`
And then use the `zipFile.getInputStream(fileHeader)` to write them to another outputstream.